# Scraperwiki Python Loop Issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, css-selectors, lxml, scraperwiki

I'm creating a scraper through ScraperWiki using Python, but I'm having an issue with the results I get. I'm basing my code off the [basic example](https://scraperwiki.com/help/code-in-your-browser/) on ScraperWiki's docs and everything seems very similar, so I'm not sure where my issue is. For my results, I get the first documents title/URL that is on the page, but there seems to be a problem with the loop, as it does not return the remaining documents after that one. Any advice is appreciated!

```
import scraperwiki
import requests
import lxml.html

html = requests.get("http://www.store.com/us/a/productDetail/a/910271.htm").content
dom = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

for entry in dom.cssselect('.downloads'):
    document = {
        'title': entry.cssselect('a')[0].text_content(),
        'url': entry.cssselect('a')[0].get('href')
    }
    print document
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `a` tags inside the `div` with class `downloads`:

```
for entry in dom.cssselect('.downloads a'):
    document = {
        'title': entry.text_content(),
        'url': entry.get('href')
    }
    print document
```

Prints:

```
{'url': '/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1012741_4.pdf', 'title': 'Rough In/Spec Sheet'}
{'url': '/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1012741_2.pdf', 'title': 'Installation and Care Guide with Service Parts'}
{'url': '/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1204921_2.pdf', 'title': 'Installation and Care Guide without Service Parts'}
{'url': '/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1011610_2.pdf', 'title': 'Installation Guide without Service Parts'}
```